# SwiftUI: Is it possible to trigger a set PreferenceKey() from inside an .OnTapGesture?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am developing an App with the following ContentView Structure

```
    ContentView {
    ---HeaderView
    ---Collection view using QGrid (An Array of Cells), data source: an array of Structs
    ---A Detail View of data from a single data Struct from the data array
}
```

The goal is to update the Detail subView with data from a tapped cell in the QGrid.
I have a cell view which recognizes taps and correctly reports which cell to Console. The .OnTap correctly modifies the Cell view, but I can only attach the Preference setting to outside the Cell view, so it triggers the change in Pref every time a cell is displayed in QGrid leaving the reported cell as the last one in the grid, but never updates to the selected cell when tapped!

```
struct GlyphCell: View {

    var glyph:Glyph

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("\(glyph.Hieroglyph)")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(.all, 12.0)
                .font(.system(size: 40.0))
                .background(Color.yellow)
            Text("\(glyph.Gardiner)")
                .offset(x: 12, y: 26)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.onTapGesture {
            print("Tap on \(self.glyph.Gardiner)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // would like to update preference in here!
                }
            }
        .preference(key: TappedGlyphPreferenceKey.self, value: self.glyph)
        .cornerRadius(6.0)
        .frame(width: 90.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Can this be accomplished with this approach, i.e., passing a Pref up to a parent view then down to the target Detail view?  I tried both State and Observables wrappers on the selected data Struct but got nowhere with them.  Any thoughts welcome!

Update: I must have a faulty understanding of State/Bind. I have a @State var of the data Struct in the parent Content View which I use update the Detail subView.  When I added the @Bind of that Struct var to the Cell subview, the compiler then needs me to add that var to the parameter list for the Cell Sub-view. When I add it, I get all kinds of errors. I tried a number of variants, but gave up on Bind to try prefs. Recall, I want to pass the selected Cell Struct up the tree, then down to Detail.  I can try to recreate the error if you would be generous enough to take a peek.

Comment: If read only text then first I've got in mind is `@Binding`. Anything wrong with it?

Comment: I had trouble passing the data containing Struct, which is btw, read-only.

Comment: *Selection* is view-state feature, so your DetailView can have `@State` `selectedGlyph` and pass binding to it into each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (cannot test it due to many dependencies absent, so just idea)

```
struct GlyphCell: View {

    var glyph:Glyph

    @State private var selected = false   // << track own selection
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("\(glyph.Hieroglyph)")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(.all, 12.0)
                .font(.system(size: 40.0))
                .background(Color.yellow)
            Text("\(glyph.Gardiner)")
                .offset(x: 12, y: 26)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.onTapGesture {
            print("Tap on \(self.glyph.Gardiner)")
            self.selected.toggle() // << async not required here
        }
        .cornerRadius(6.0)
        .frame(width: 90.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        .background(Group {
           if self.selected {
                // activate preference only when selected
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: TappedGlyphPreferenceKey.self, value: self.glyph)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should not the State var be within the top level, and the subviews have a Bind var?  I am suffering with sparse and contradictory documentation   ;).  Also, if Private, is not the parent excluded from access?

Comment: State is by-design intended to be modifiable only within owning view, so make it private is good practice. View can pass binding to some other view, but owner of state is not changed.

Comment: OK, I understand what you did by creating the local selected variable (for internal use in Cell) detecting a selection to trigger the change in prefKey!  It works to the extent that the selected struct is passed into the PrefKey.  Now, the issue is that .OnPrefChanged in the parent view is only called on first loading the view, not ever on selecting a cell in grid, even though, as noted above the new data is passed to the Pref.  I'm going to work this up for while. Many thanks for the insights!!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach:
Keep the preference value as a State variable.
On tap gesture change the state variable.
Attach preference modifier to the view and set the State variable as preference value.